# Python: Edit Google App engine default login page ( _ah/login )

Tags: python, google-app-engine

The import statement on Python is `from google.appengine.api import users` ...
The code for retrieving user data is `users.get_current_user()`.
The code for creating a login page is `users.create_login_url(self.request.uri)`
The sign in url shall be created. Once the user clicks it, they shall be redirected to this page

How do I edit this page? I would like to customize it. I know I can set my own username & password textfields but then I have to maintain session data. Google have already done this so it's regressive for me to repeat.

The example project is available at [Guest Book - web app engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingusers)

The question is how do I edit this page? or How can I use the users API to store session data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that I cannot use the google api to do a custom authentication from [stack overflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706678/how-to-users-set-current-user)